# python countdown timer issue(doesn't work)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I made a countdown timer with tkinter. However, when "if (state):" is inserted, the timer is not displayed. I want to display the timer when it is not started at first. There is also a problem that the stop button does not work during operation.

sorry my english

I removed "if (state):" and "state = False". Then the timer is displayed, but it starts from the beginning.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from tkinter import *


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Timer")
root.geometry("980x640")

sec = 100


def main():
     if (state):
        for x in range(sec, -1, -1):
             lbl1["text"] = str(formatTime(x))
             root.update()
             time.sleep(1)

def formatTime(x):
    minutes, seconds_rem = divmod(x, 60)
    return "%02d:%02d" % (minutes, seconds_rem)


def start():
    global state
    state = True

def stop():
    global state
    state = False

def reset():
    global sec
    sec = 1800

def add1min():
    global sec
    sec += 60

def rm1min():
    global sec
    if sec > 60:
       sec -= 60

state = False


startButton = tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=start)
startButton.pack(fill = 'x', padx=30, side = 'left')
startButton.pack()

stopButton = tk.Button(root, text='Stop', command=stop)
stopButton.pack(fill = 'x', padx=30, side = 'left')
stopButton.pack()

resetButton = tk.Button(root, text='Reset', command=reset)
resetButton.pack(fill = 'x', padx=30, side = 'left')
resetButton.pack()

add1minButton = tk.Button(root, text='+1 min', command=add1min)
add1minButton.pack(fill = 'x', padx=30, side = 'left')
add1minButton.pack()


rm1minButton = tk.Button(root, text='-1 min', command=rm1min)
rm1minButton.pack(fill = 'x', padx=30, side = 'left')
rm1minButton.pack()


lbl1 = Label()
lbl1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
main()
root.mainloop()
```

no error code

Comment: You've tagged this with both `python-2.7` and `python-3.x`; which version are you actually using? The answer may depend on that

Comment: I using python-3.x.

Comment: instead of sleep you can use `root.after(milliseconds, function)` and then you don't need `root.update()` and it doesn't stop other functions in tkinter: [timer-using-after](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/timer-using-after)

Comment: I will try "root.after(milliseconds, function)". Thx

Answer (score 2):

You don't go into your `Start()` function until after your have gone into `main()` and so `state` remains `False` and your `main()` function will not display your timer.  Try calling the `main()` again AFTER you have pressed your button.

Comment: I am a beginner in programming. I don't know what to do. Can you write the code that calls the function?

Comment: That's a bit of a silly question, of course it is possible to write code that calls a function, you have done so many times in your example.  What might work is adding a line `main()` to your `start()` function at the end.  Don't forget to indent it so that it is part of the function!

Comment: Sorry. It was a stupid question.
I will try it myself. Thx!

Comment: Do not be sorry, it brought a smile to me.  Good luck!